# Running server using docker server starts but request not reaching server

Tags: docker

I am trying to run my server using a docker image 
I pull the docker image on my local system 
and run it, the server starts and everything seems fine but when i send a request to the server through postman I get " could not get any response " the request does not reach my server

I am sending the request to http://127.0.0.1:4000

server is running on 127.0.0.1:4000

docker pull image_name
docker run image_name

I also tried giving docker run -p 4000:4000 image_name

My docker file:

```
FROM python:3
EXPOSE 4000
CMD command to run server
```

Any ideas what i could be doing wrong or what should i do to get this working

I get the response when i get into the docker image bash and send the curl command

Comment: What image are you trying to run? Most likely the application is running on port 80 inside the container so your port mapping would need to be 4000:80

Comment: @NickSpicer i am running a image that i created, added it in the description  i will try that mapping and let you know

Comment: I get the same result with 4000:80

Comment: You app should listen on `*:80` within the container, and you should connect using `(host):4000`

Comment: @FrankNielsen didn't quite catch you there so my server should run on http://127.0.0.1:80 ? and my request should be http://127.0.0.1:4000?

Comment: If the server is listening on 127.0.0.1, it will be unreachable from outside its container; it needs to listen on the special “all interfaces” address 0.0.0.0.

Comment: i changed it to 0.0.0.0 and now its working ty @DavidMaze

Comment: @DavidMaze btw why doesnt just 127.0.0.1 work?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 / localhost` is a loopback interface, and can only be seen from the machine itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think 4000 is already is in used within your system try to run python server on different port or check your python server is running on 4000 because you have EXPOSE at 4000 so this means that your docker container and python server both are running on 4000:4000 .